# emacs上で，ことえりから「．」と「。」を切り替えて入力する方法

Tags: macos, emacs

普段日本語のパンクチュエーションを「．」「，」に設定していますが，場合によって「。」「、」の入力が必要になるときがあります．このとき，emacs以外の入力環境においては（他にもあるかもしれませんが）option+「．」「，」で「。」「、」を入力することができます．

ところが，emacsではoptionが（Metaキーに割り当てていなくても）通常のaltとは異なる機能を持っているため，上記のように入力文字の切り替えに使うことができません．

そこで質問です．

1. optionをemacs上で，上記のような入力文字の切り替えに使う方法はあるのでしょうか？
2. option以外のキーを入力文字の切り替えに使う方法はあるのでしょうか？
3. デフォルトで割り当てられているoptionの機能を停止させるなどすると，入力文字の切り替えに使えるようになりますでしょうか？

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacのどのEmacsでも使用できるかわかりませんが
変数ns-alternate-modifierの設定を変更してはどうでしょうか？

describe-variableでns-alternate-modifierを指定して
以下のような記述が出てくれば、この変数の値をnoneに変更することで
通常のalt/optionに割り当てることができると思います。

> ns-alternate-modifier is a variable defined in ‘C source code’. Its
>   value is ‘none’ Original value was meta
>
> Documentation: This variable describes the behavior of the alternate
>   or option key. Set to control, meta, alt, super, or hyper means it is
>   taken to be that key. Set to none means that the alternate / option
>   key is not interpreted by Emacs at all, allowing it to be used at a
>   lower level for accented character entry.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 23.1 of Emacs.

そのままcustomizeを選択するか、またはinit.elに

```
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'none)
```

とすればOKです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．
お教えいただいた
`(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'none)`
の記述を設定に追加したところ，希望通り，他のエディタ上のoptionキーの挙動に設定されたようです．
ご教示まことに感謝いたします．

なお，
`(describe-variable ns-alternate-modifier)`
を実行してみたところ，以下のように出力されました．

```
meta is void as a variable.

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.
```

Comment: うまくやりたいことができたようでよかったです。`(describe-variable ns-alternate-modifier)`は、M-x describe-variableしたあとで、ns-alternate-modifilerと入力してもらえれば、意図した結果になったと思います。または`(describe-variable 'ns-alternate-modifier)`というようにクォートすれば、ミニバッファに説明が表示されます。